# Taking a screenshot in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, screenshot

On startup I'd like the application I am making to load a background image of the current app layout on my phone - screenshot. Is this feasible?

This would have to be done every single time when opened in case new apps are downloaded or wallpaper is changed when app not in use.